# Alinear columna concatenada en una consulta en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT A.CODIGO_MINSA, A.DESCRIPCION,  B.DESCRIPCION AS COLEGIO, 
A.CODIGO_MINSA + ' - ' + A.DESCRIPCION + SPACE(60 - LEN(A.DESCRIPCION)) + '- 
' +  B.DESCRIPCION  AS PRESENTACION
FROM [HEVES_RRHH].[dbo].[T_TIPO_ESPECIALIDAD] A LEFT JOIN  [HEVES_RRHH]. 
[dbo].[T_COLEGIOS_PROFESIONALES] B ON A.CODIGO_COLEGIO = B.CODIGO_MINSA
```

Concatena 3 columnas y en `PRESENTACION`, arroja lo siguiente:

```
1-ADMINISTRACION DE HOSPITALES          - COLEGIO MEDICO DEL PERU
2-CIRUGÍA BUCAL MÁXILO FACIAL      - COLEGIO ODONTOLOGICO DEL PERU
3-PSICOLOGÍA CLÍNICA Y DE LA SALUD    - COLEGIO DE PSICOLOGOS DEL PERU
```

Mi objetivo es que el resultado salga alineado, así:

```
1-ADMINISTRACION DE HOSPITALES     - COLEGIO MEDICO DEL PERU
2-CIRUGÍA BUCAL MÁXILO FACIAL      - COLEGIO ODONTOLOGICO DEL PERU
3-PSICOLOGÍA CLÍNICA Y DE LA SALUD - COLEGIO DE PSICOLOGOS DEL PERU
```

Usé el comando `SPACE`, con el total de caracteres a 60, supuse que al restar de la longitud de descripción y añadirle con espacios, debería salir alineado.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: `A.DESCRIPCION` es `CHAR` o `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Hola amigo, es varchar(100)

Comment: ¿Y las columnas no tienen espacios?, otra forma es hacer: `LEFT(A.DESCRIPCION + SPACE(60), 60)`

Comment: Olvida lo anterior, con o sin espacios tu código debería funcionar igual, tal vez la columna tenga algún otro caracter tipo `tab`?

Comment: No, no tiene otro caracter, solo el texto que contiene la columna, pero no logro alinearlo...

Comment: ¿Que collate tiene tu base de datos y las columnas? Estoy haciendo pruebas acá y me funciona bien con el query publicado.

Comment: Ambas tablas tienen el collate : Modern_Spanish_CI_AS, la BD general y otras BD tienen : Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

Comment: He probado con varios collates y una consulta con la misma base de tu código funciona bien, sin problemas.

Answer (score 1):

No he probado tu código, pero me parece que funciona bien.

El problema es que sql server muestra los resultados con una fuente que no es monoespaciada, es decir, la letra 'W' ocupa mas espacio que la letra 'I'. La solución sería dejar el query como está y al mostrarlo en tu aplicación utilizar una fuente monoespaciada.

Dejo esta imagen para explicar mi punto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada registro tiene 10 letras al principio

La siguiente información te puede interesar:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font
https://www.gusl.org.ve/2014/07/22/15-fuentes-monoespaciadas-para-programadores/

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  unidadmed_id||'    '|| RPAD(und_descripcion,20,' ')||lpad(und_nomenclatura,3,'.')as Unidad_medidas   from spu_unidadMedida
```

En oracle lo hice de esta manera y funciona
Imagen de resultado

[image: Imagen de resultado]